# Prevent adding name attribute when using pandas dataframe to_file() method

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, geopandas

I have a geopandas.GeoDataFrame. When I want to dump it into a file, it adds a "name" attribute that will be the name of the file I passed. How to prevent this?

```
df = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(data, geometry="geometry")
# some logic here
df.to_file(filename="a_random_name.geojson", driver="GeoJSON")
```

inside a_random_name.geosjon:

```
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "a_random_name",
"features": [...]
```

to_file method adds the "name" attribute to my data frame and I want to prevent that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- you have not provided sample data,  so have used **naturalearth_lowres**
- as you can see no random **name** key has been added.  Expected **name** keys are present to define the CRS

```
import geopandas
import json
from pathlib import Path

data = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))

df = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(data, geometry="geometry").sample(3)
df.to_file(filename="a_random_name.geojson", driver="GeoJSON")

with open(Path.cwd().joinpath("a_random_name.geojson")) as f:
    geojson = json.load(f)

# exclude geometry for SO answer    
{
    k: v
    if k != "features"
    else [{kk: vv for kk, vv in f.items() if kk != "geometry"} for f in v]
    for k, v in geojson.items()
}
```

#### output

```
{'type': 'FeatureCollection',
 'crs': {'type': 'name',
  'properties': {'name': 'urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84'}},
 'features': [{'type': 'Feature',
   'properties': {'pop_est': 4917000.0,
    'continent': 'Oceania',
    'name': 'New Zealand',
    'iso_a3': 'NZL',
    'gdp_md_est': 206928}},
  {'type': 'Feature',
   'properties': {'pop_est': 9746117.0,
    'continent': 'North America',
    'name': 'Honduras',
    'iso_a3': 'HND',
    'gdp_md_est': 25095}},
  {'type': 'Feature',
   'properties': {'pop_est': 1912789.0,
    'continent': 'Europe',
    'name': 'Latvia',
    'iso_a3': 'LVA',
    'gdp_md_est': 34102}}]}
```